# Javascript in html multiple functions

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-apps-script

I'm coding a google apps script website/project at the moment and I'm facing a problem in my HTML file which calls javascript functions.

I had one function, which uses DOM manipulation to change a divs content when I click different buttons.

However if I want to add another function (which doesn't even has to do something with my first function) in my `<script>` element and I run the application, the first function doesn't work at all and nothing happens when I click a button.

```
<?!= include('CSS'); ?>
<body>
<div id="header">
<h1>Auction System Software Engineering1</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">  
<button class="myButton" id="registration"  
onclick="changeCenter('regForm')"> Registration </button><br>
<button class="myButton" id="searchItem"  
onclick="changeCenter('search')"> Search Items </button><br>
<div id="logIn"> <?var url = getScriptUrl();?>
<form id="loginform" action='<?=url?>?page=LoggedIn' target='_top'>
username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br>
password:
 <input type="password" name="password"/>
 <input type="submit" id="loginBtn" value="Login"/>
</form> 
</div>
</div>
<div id="section">
<div id="regForm" style="display:none">
<form id="myForm">
 <fieldset>
 First name:  <input name="prename" type="text" /> <br>
 Second name: <input name="surname" type="text" /> <br>
 birthday: <input name="bday" type="text" /> <br>
 adress: <input name="adress" type="text" /> <br>
 username: <input name="unameReg" type="text" /> <br>
 password: <input name="pwReg" type="password" /> <br>
 repeat password: <input name="pwReg2" type="password" /> <br>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" />
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </div>
```

this is the HTML layout

```
<script> 
// this is the function to change html parts dynamically, like f.e. when 
clicking a registration button, the welcome center section dissapears 
and the registration form will be activated

function changeCenter(divID){
//Hide the currently shown element first
if(document.getElementById("Welcome").style.display == 'block'){
document.getElementById("Welcome").style.display = 'none';
}
else if (document.getElementById("search").style.display == 'block'){
document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
}
else if (document.getElementById("regForm").style.display == 'block'){
document.getElementById("regForm").style.display = 'none';
}
//display the element that will be shown.  No content is injected yet
document.getElementById(divID).style.display = 'block';
}

function testingXY{

}
</script>
```

if I delete function testingXY it will work and I can change the center again but when it's added it won't work. Hope this code help you out now.

```
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Main').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

that's my .gs code line which will be executed after the apps script app is opened (trough doGet(e) method)

Comment: So you've shown code that works, and not even shown how `changeCentre` is executed ... my guess is, the problem you are having is in the code you haven't shown

Comment: Yes, please show what you did that made the code not work.

Comment: @JaromandaX its updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function declaration is faulty. It is missing parenthesis

```
//yours
function testingXY{

    }

    This should be like this
    //edited
    function testingXY(){

    }
```

Comment: oh my god, i was just missing that by not looking right. Thanks